# mouse click 2d array registration

Tags: java, arrays, memory, mouse, boolean

Hey everybody I'm making a memory game where it's a 4x4 board and you click the tiles to reveal what's underneath and you have to find the corresponding picture. I'm having trouble with the logic behind the mouse clicking and assigning them to a guess1 and guess2.

the Joption panel is how I'm testing to see if guess 1 and guess 2 register. Every time guess1 works fine, but I don't know how to make the second guess work
Here is my attempt.

```
public void displayHit(Graphics g)
{
    //earlier on in the code mouseClicked provides the x and y indexes for the place where you click
    if (mouseClicked)
    {
        //method I coded to assign whereever you clicked on the 400x400 board to match the 4x4 array
        centerClick(x1,y1);
        guess1 = board[row][column];
        board[row][column] = board[x1][y1];
        guess1 = board[x1][y1];
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(guess1 + "this is guess1");
        guess2 = -1;
        setColor(g);
        centerHit(xMouse, yMouse);
        g.fillOval(xMouse, yMouse, 40, 40);
        mouseClicked = false;

     if ((guess2 == -1) && (mouseClicked))
    {
        centerClick(x1,y1);
        guess2 = board[row][column];
        board[row][column] = board[x1][y1];
        guess2 = board[x1][y1];
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(guess2 + "this is guess2");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 boolean guess2Flag;    
 if (mouseClicked)
{

    if(!guess2Flag) 
    {
    centerClick(x1,y1);
    guess1 = board[row][column];
    board[row][column] = board[x1][y1];
    guess1 = board[x1][y1];
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(guess1 + "this is guess1");
    guess2Flag = true;
    setColor(g);
    centerHit(xMouse, yMouse);
    g.fillOval(xMouse, yMouse, 40, 40);
    mouseClicked = false;
    }

    else if (guess2Flag)
    {
    centerClick(x1,y1);
    guess2 = board[row][column];
    board[row][column] = board[x1][y1];
    guess2 = board[x1][y1];
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(guess2 + "this is guess2");
    guess2Flag = false;
    mouseClicked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: that still has the same problems I've been encountering. WHen I click on a tile it reveals "this is guess1" and then immediately after "this is guess2", so it  running through the whole thing everytime and not seperating

Comment: ok I got it now. I had to also add 

mouseClicked = false;

then add it to the 2nd if statement. Thanks for that advice. I should have used booleans instead of an int

Comment: Yeah I forgot that, but that should work!  If your problem is resolved you accept an answer by clicking the "check mark" by the answer you think is correct.

Comment: I updated my answer as well, you should probably go for the "else if" on the second conditional so that only one will fire per mouse click no matter what.  Good luck!

Comment: @mskudia

I don't want to use the "else if" because I build on the if statement and if I use else if then I can't use my next "if" statement to check if they are similar. Thanks for the advice though

Answer (score 0):

while (mouseClicked)

this looks bad. It either means that you are either not releasing the UI thread to get a second click, or you are calling graphics operations in a non UI thread.

Comment: I was originally using if else statements I forgot to change it back I was just messing around. Updated it now